# What happens when a temporary self-signed SSL certificate is replaced with a trusted certificate?

Tags: security-certificate

My website is in beta stage. I am using a temporary self-signed SSL certificate with a short expiry date. Beta users have to add the exception on their browser to access HTTPS on my website. Subsequently, I will be replacing the certificate with a trusted one from a Certificate Authority.

Upon replacement of the self-signed certificate with a trusted certificate, do these beta users need to do anything to access my site on HTTPS, such as deleting the self-signed certificate on their browser manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get a genuine certificate, you can replace your self-signed certificate and not worry about your users.  Any user that had previously accepted the self signed certificate will be able to view the site with the genuine certificate without taking any special actions.   They will not have to delete their acceptance of the self-signed certificate.

Comment: Note that in high security environments, I do recommend users purge such test certificates. You don't want any legacy certificates laying about that could be potentially confused for production ones.

Comment: Thanks for the assurance. Can you provide a reason why you say so?